# why are my cylinders stretched if i use this geometry setup

Tags: geometry-nodes

i have this very simple geometry nodes setup:

[image]

result is:

[image]

my cylinders are stretched. I would have expected that the cylinder form is the same, but the just got bigger distances. Why is that?

blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you're doing the operation *(in this case add on x-positions)* after instancing the cylinder. So, you're modifying the x-position of each vertex of the instanced cylinder instead of the x-position of the points that you used for instancing.

Thus, you have to first modify the x-position points then use them for instancing of cylinders,
[image]